# How to use `re.findall` to extract data from string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have the following string (file):

```
s = '''
\newcommand{\commandName1}{This is first command}

\newcommand{\commandName2}{This is second command with {} brackets inside
in multiple lines {} {}
}

\newcommand{\commandName3}{This is third, last command}

'''
```

Now I would like to use Python `re` package to extract the data to dictionary where `key` is the command name (`\commandName1`, `\commandName2` and `\commandName3`) and the values are the `This is first command`, `This is second command with {} brackets inside in multiple lines {} {}` and `This is third, last command`. I tried sth like:

`re.findall(r'\\newcommand{(.+)}{(.+)}', s)`

but it doesnt work because second command has `{}` inside. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: You can use: `\\newcommand{([^}]+)}{(.+)}`

Comment: It doesnt work for the above example (edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```py
(?s)\\newcommand{([^}]+)}{(.+?)}(?=\s*(?:\\newcommand|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY3KDd/2)

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/FOdUYF)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `(?s)`: Enable DOTALL (single line) mode
- `\\newcommand`:
- `{`: Match a `{`
- `([^}]+)`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `{` in capture group #1
- `}`: Match a `}`
- `{`: Match a `{`
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any characters in capture group #2
- `}`: Match a `}`
- `(?=\s*(?:\\newcommand|$))`: Lookahead to assert presence of 0 or more whitespace and `\newcommand` or else end of input.

**Code:**

```py
import re

s = r'''
\newcommand{\commandName1}{This is first command}

\newcommand{\commandName2}{This is second command with {} brackets inside
in multiple lines {} {}
}

\newcommand{\commandName3}{This is third, last command}
'''

print (re.findall(r'(?s)\\newcommand{([^}]+)}{(.+?)}(?=\s*(?:\\newcommand|$))', s))
```

Comment: The following doesnt work (it founds only the first command
`re.findall('\\newcommand{([^}]+)}{(.+?)}(?=\s*\\newcommand|\Z)', s)`

Comment: And this found only the first two commands:
`re.findall('\\newcommand{([^}]+)}{(.+?)}(?=\s*\\newcommand|\Z)', s, re.DOTALL)
`

Comment: @Jason: I have updated my answer to show suggested code and added an online code demo as well.

Comment: Reason why it didn't work for you earlier was presence of few whitespaces/line-breaks before end of input i.e. `\Z`

Answer (score 2):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E3VajJ/1)):

```py
import re

s = r"""\newcommand{\commandName1}{This is first command}

\newcommand{\commandName2}{This is second command with {} brackets inside
in multiple lines {} {}
}

\newcommand{\commandName3}{This is third, last command}

"""

out = re.findall(
    r"^\\newcommand\{(.*?)\}\{((?:(?!^\\newcommand).)+)\}", s, flags=re.S | re.M
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ("\\commandName1", "This is first command"),
    (
        "\\commandName2",
        "This is second command with {} brackets inside\nin multiple lines {} {}\n",
    ),
    ("\\commandName3", "This is third, last command"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you, could please explain jut last regex used to match the value of command?

Comment: This will slow down considerably for longer text since it is performing a negative lookahead before matching every character. Even with the current sample text it is taking almost double of the steps than the regex in my answer

Comment: @Jason It's called *Tempered Greedy Token*. Wiktor has good answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat

Comment: Even that answer mentioned that *Tempered Greedy Token is resource consuming* moreover this problem doesn't even require that.